# CodeIgniter issue with using the back button

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, jquery-mobile

I have a web application which allows a user to perform a search which produces a paginated set of results. The user can then select one of the items from the results to see more information. When the user, however, presses the back button it produces an `Error loading page` error from jQuery Mobile. From looking at the Preview in Chrome Inspector this is due to a `1064` error (an error in my SQL syntax). Given that the query works when first executed i'm thinking this isn't really the problem.

Not being too experienced with the CodeIgniter, my guess is that when the back button is pressed the controller method isn't being sent the required values to return a valid response - hence the error.

Can anyone help with this issue as I want the user to be able to return to the search results and paginate back and forth as they please.

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND `library`.`votes` >= '1000'AND `library`.`language` != 'German'AND `ro' at line 5

SELECT *FROM (`library`)JOIN `classifications` ON `library`.`id` = `classifications`.`id`WHERE `library`.`rating` >=AND `library`.`votes` >= '1000'AND `library`.`language` != 'German'AND `classifications`.`meter` >ORDER BY `library`.`rating` DESC

Filename: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/libraryTest/models/results_model.php

Line Number: 53
```

**EDIT**

The problems seems to be, as i said above, that the controller method is not accepting any arguments when the back button is presses such that it tries to execute the following query with no values:

```
SELECT *FROM (`library`)JOIN `classifications` ON `library`.`id` = `classifications`.`id`WHERE `library`.`rating` >=AND `library`.`votes` >= '1000'AND `library`.`language` != 'German'AND `classifications`.`meter` >ORDER BY `library`.`rating` DESC
```

You can see that the values for `library.rating` and `classifications.meter` are not present. But I'd like to reiterate that these values are present in the initial query when the controller method is first called. This error occurs on navigating back to the page.

Line 53 above corresponds to the execution of the SQL query in the model method:

`return $sql_query->get()->result();`

Comment: The code has been added - as I said though, the query executes successfully when the values are actually passed to the controller

Answer (score 0):

```
'AND `library`.`votes` >= '1000'AND `library`.`language` != 'German'AND `ro'
```

at the end of that line you have : `AND 'ro'`

check your syntax. from where is that? that's a wrong condition.
It should be something like:

```
AND language != ro
```

Please paste here line number 53! Because there's the problem.